# BouncyCastle Provider JCE Authentication Security Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, bouncycastle, provider

I've a Java applet that uses the bouncycastle library.
When I run the application on Eclipse, everything works ok, but when I use the applet on a browser with the  tag, it is thrown an exception when I add a security bouncycastleprovider.

My stackTrace is:

```
java.io.IOException: error constructing MAC: java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKPKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source) at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48.jar and bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar version of the bouncycastle.
Why does the applet on a browser can't add a securityprovider?

Thank you,
Regards,
William.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the rights to do so.

1. Which java version are you using?
2. Did you [sign](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/signing_applet_code_does_not) your applet with an official certificate?
3. Did you set the correct [flags/attributes](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias) in the manifest/jnlp files?

You may try to decrease the java security slider in the system properties to medium to be able to run it. If you use a self signed certificate you may add it to the java trust store

**Update:**

- Which exact version are you using? (Please write the full version like 1.7.0_51)
- And as already pointed out: If you run your applet in eclipse it will work but it will **not** work if you run it in a webbrowser (due to security restrictions of the browser plugin). If you want to run your applet in a webbrowser you must do one of the following:

  - Sign it with an official certificate OR
  - Lower the security slider in the java system settings to medium
  - Add your self sign certificate to the java truststore
- And one more thing: You need to ensure that your applet and **all** your external libs are signed with the **same** certificate. I know that bouncycasle libs are already signed if you download them - so you have to remove this signing information before you sign it with your certificate

Comment: I'm using JRE7 version, it is like I said, in eclipse it works fine. Not with an official certificate, but with a self-signed.. Other jars work ok, but not this bouncycastle one. How do I set the flags/attributes in the manifest/jnlp? Which files are those ones?